# How can I switch back to the previous version of Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser

I can see that under C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application there is a folder for the previous version of Chrome there. I'm doing some testing and would like to revert back to that version. I tried removing the folder for the newest version and launching Chrome which crashes. How can I tell Chrome to use that old version?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to just tell chrome to use a different version.

You could try to download tge version you want from this link:
http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/

Or portable versions so you will not have to uninstall the current version and keep as many versions as you want in your pc:
https://google-chrome-portable.en.uptodown.com/old

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to install an old version of Chrome which can be found on [Old Version](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/), and then [turn off the auto-update](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates) feature BEFORE opening Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Just turn off the auto update feature in Chrome, uninstall it and then install the older version. But you would need the 33 or older installer.